# How to check whether a command is run with range or not?

Tags: vimscript, command-line, visual-mode, functions, range

For example, I have the following code

```
command! -range Test call TestFunc()
function! TestFunc() abort
  " if run with range
  "   get selected content
  " else
  "   get current word under the cursor
  " endif
endfunction
```

I want to differentiate whether users run `:Test` or `:'<,'>Test`.

I've tested `mode()` function doesn't work here. Also `<line1>`,`<line2>` do not help because they always give me the same result(current line number) when I run it with range(select the current line) or not.

I wonder if there are any solutions for this?

Comment: Since you mentioned word under the cursor, consider implementing an *operator* that takes a motion/text object rather than a command that takes a range. The latter is limited to lines only when passed a range. See [Grep Operator](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/33.html) from "Learn Vimscript the Hard Way" for an example operator. (You might want to consider reading the whole material, it's an excellent resource if you want to master Vimscript.)

Comment: @filbranden Thanks, I'll read it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A range with commands is always about lines. It seems you want to work with line/column positions.

Whether a range was given can be checked by using `<range>`:

```
command! -range Test call TestFunc(<range>,<line1>,<line2>)
function! TestFunc(r,l1,l2) abort
    if a:r == 0
        echo "No range"
    elseif a:r == 1
        echo "Single Line given (like :22Test)"
    else
        echo "Line range given (like 1,23Test, '<,'>Test or %Test)"
    endif
endfunction
```

Note: You might need to `set cmdheight=2` to see the echo in all cases.

Comment: Implementing this as presented, it works as expected. Implemented in another function, 'l1' and 'l2' get passed as expected, but 'r' comes with a code of '2'. So the func thinks it's in error, when the range is fine. What can be going on? What does code 2 mean?

Comment: 0 means no Range, 1 Single line Range, 2 multiline Range. So 2 is handele by the Else Branche.

Comment: ah - 'h: <range>' says <range> code 0, 1, or 2 represents "the number of items in the command range". So 2 is not an error code, but an indication that the range had two values.

Comment: Are these `0`,`1`,`2` even documented in the `:help`? I was struggling to understand them. Thanks for your explanation anyway...!