# How to get both the start and end (row, col) of the visual-selected region in `nvim_create_user_command`?

Tags: neovim, range, user-commands

I want to create a user command that can get the visual-selected text (may across multiple lines) from users when the command is calling upon the `v`-selected range. (so the cursor columns of both the start&end of the visual region matter)
Currently, I can only get the rows info of the selected region from `line1`, `line2` in the callback/handler by setting `range=true` in the option of `nvim_create_user_command`, but how about the columns?

I also found this [great old answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24796/10189) on the Vim side but it only mentioned about getting the starting and ending rows, but I also need the columns info to get the exact selected text.

Comment: User commands are typically linewise. If you want something invoked from visual mode, use `xnoremap`. But: try getting the column information out of the `'<` and `'>` marks.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for the hint.